# Why does LINQ-to-SQL generate this SQL statement for a comparison

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

if I have a LINQ to SQL query like this:

```
var query = from x in db.XTable
            select x.y == 123; // the y column is nullable!
List<bool> list = query.ToList();
```

it will generate a SQL statement that will contain this:

```
(CASE 
    WHEN [t0].[y] = 123 THEN 1
    WHEN NOT ([t0].[y] = 123) THEN 0
    ELSE NULL
END)
```

which will throw an error cause null could not get assigned to bool. I know why this happens (because a comparison in SQL with null is always false) but I don't know why LINQ to SQL does not use a stetement like this:

```
(CASE 
    WHEN [t0].[y] = 123 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END)
```

which would work.

Can I push LINQ to SQL to do this?

Comment: Technically, a comparision in SQL with null is always `unknown`, not `false`, otherwise `IF (NOT NULL=1)` would be true, but it's not.  `NULL=1` is `unknown`, and `NOT unknown` is `unknown` which is not `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, as you state, because you must think the `SQL` way with linq to sql, not the object way...

It might be considered as a bug or as a feature, by the way...

Especially with null values.

For example, concatenation of nullable `string` is different in linq to sql and linq to objects.

Assuming a and b are strings :

```
from n in db
select n.a + n.b
```

in linq to sql, if a is null and b is not, a + b = null

in linq to object if a is null anb b is not a + b  = b

to get the same result in linq to sql, you'll have to use the coalesce operator `select (a ?? string.Empty) + b`

Anyway, you can either return a list of `Nullable<bool>` and a list of `bool` which would be :

```
from x in db.XTable
select x.y != null && x.y == 123
```

or

```
from x in db.XTable
select (x.y ?? 0) == 123
```

But to get what you want in linq to objects, you would have to do

```
from x in db.XTable.ToList()
select (x.y== null ? (bool?)null : x.y== 123))
```

**EDIT**

This might change in [future versions](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015361-incorrect-handling-of-null-variables-in-where-cl) (not sure if the given case will be included)